# apt complains about change of Suite from testing to stable

Tags: debian, apt, distributions, software-updates, devuan

I'm trying to `apt-get update` my Debian or Devuan distribution, but am getting an error:

```
Get:14 http://deb.devuan.org//merged beowulf InRelease [25.6 kB]                                                                                                                                                         
E: Repository 'http://deb.devuan.org//merged beowulf InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'testing' to 'stable'                                                                                                     
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

I haven't changed anything in my apt lists file, nor do I have the word "testing" anywhere in there. Also, I can't quite understand what I'm supposed to do with `apt-secure`. What's going on and what should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Congratulations! You've "stuck" with a `testing` release of your distribution (in your case, Devuan) all the way, and now it's become the stable release version!

This is not a problem. You just have to tell apt to accept this change, like so:

```
apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change
```

and that should do it.

Comment: I had to run this *twice* to make it work.